# Load a picture in a webpage from Flash

Tags: php, flash, http, session, cookies

I'm editing a web page to access it only after login, so now it's a php page with an inital 
`<?php session_start(); ?>` 
and in the body of the page I test the value of a session variable.

All works fine but in the header there is flash animation that don't load background picture.
In the old version of the page this picture was loaded fine but not now.

The address of old version of the page is [this](http://www.communityconnectionsrelocation.com/pages/bayarea.html) and new versione is this [this](http://www.communityconnectionsrelocation.com/pages/bayarea.php)

I think all depends on php session but I don't know any way to resolve this problem.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

The background picture is loading fine correctly. Its error with your flash movie... file. It is overlapping the background picture and hidding it. For quick debug try changing your flash movie visibility: hidden then u can see your background image. So finally managing your flash movie will make your work

Comment: Why this problem there is only in php page and not in html page?